# Mi app android no recibe datos

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy intentando mandar 2 coordenadas (latitud y longitud) a un servidor php en netbeans. Al ejecutar el hilo lo unico que consigo es que el textview donde deberian reflejarse las mismas coordenadas enviadas por el servidor, se queda en blanco.

Este es el hilo que se ejecuta al pulsar un boton para capturar las coordenadas y enviarlas al servidor:

```
 public class Tarea extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Integer> {

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialogo = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogo.setMessage("Enviando coordenadas......");
        dialogo.setProgressStyle(dialogo.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialogo.setProgress(0);
        dialogo.setMax(100);
        dialogo.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {


            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/servidor/index2.php");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", latitud.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", longitud.getText().toString() ));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                while ((line = in.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line+NL);
                }
                in.close();
                String respuesta = sb.toString();
                capturar2.setText(respuesta);
                publishProgress();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        dialogo.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        dialogo.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Y este el código PHP en netbeans con servidor Wamp:

```
<?php
    ini_set('error_reporting',0);

    $lat=$_POST['lat'];
    $lon=$_POST['lon'];

    echo $lat."\n".$lon;

?>
```

Comment: <?php
 ini_set('error_reporting',0);

 $lat=$_POST['lat'];
 $lon=$_POST['lon'];

 echo $lat."\n".$lon;
        
?>

Comment: si ese código que acabas de agregar es relevante para tu pregunta, mejor edítala y agrégalo, no lo dejes en comentarios

Comment: no entiendo donde dices "donde deberian reflejarse las mismas coordenadas enviadas por el servidor, se queda en blanco" a que te refieres? Puedes agregar el boton o la accion que llama a la funcion asincrona?

Comment: @sioesi creo que se refiere a que donde el desea que se envíe el resultado de las *coordenadas del servidor*, pero como no trae nada, se *queda en blanco*

Comment: He visto varias veces preguntas similares a esta, generalmente el código Android no tiene problema, al consultar el php este no responde con datos por esa razón el problema. Porque no realizas debugging y aseguras que tu petición obtenga datos.

Answer (score -1):

En la clase `AsyncTask` no se puede usar `doInBackground` para hacer nada con la interfaz de usuario este corre en un hilo por separado a la interfaz. Para trabajar con la ui debe ser en los metodos `onProgressUpdate,onPostExecute,onPreExecute`

Para verificar si recive datos usa Log Ej: `Log.d("Datos:",respuesta);` y ves si funciona en la consola del Android Studio.

Para cambiar el edit y que funcione mueve `capturar2.setText(respuesta);` en el `onPostExecute`

Se cambia asi: (el ultimo parametro es String que es el tipo del resultado)

```
 public class Tarea extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
           ....
            return respuesta;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String respuesta) {
            ...
            Log.d("Datos:",respuesta);//Si quieres verlo en el log
            capturar2.setText(respuesta);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios, pero decir que al cambiar capturar2.setText(respuesta); al onPostExecute, me da error en la variable respuesta.

Comment: tienes que pasar la variable respuesta de alguna manera al  onPostExecute como es logico

Comment: Otra puntualizacion que deseo hacerles es que no utilizo el emulador, hago un build y lo cargo en la tablet.

Comment: Si  es por el Log.d sale en el Android Studio mientras tengas conectado al tablet

Comment: OK: Todo rectificado y sin errores, pero al ejecutar el hilo, la aplicacion se detiene y se cierra

Comment: Busca en google depurar en android studio vas ha ver por ejemplo https://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/470 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjzAufVT_CM asi sabes porque se te cierran las aplicaciones saludos, Ha y funciona con o sin emulador no tiene q ver

Comment: Gracias Rolando. Muy atento. Ya comentare lo que suceda.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, Rolando.

Comment: He depurado la app y he conseguido eliminar el bloqueo, pero la variable "respuesta"  sigue llegando vacia. Le he implementado un Toast antes de capturar2 y tambien vacio. ¿Puede ser el problema del php?

Comment: He llegado a la conclusion de que el problema esta en el envio o la recepcion de los datos. ¿Cual seria la solucion?